# Facebook connect dialog using without Javascript SDK Cancel button does not work

Tags: facebook, button, sdk

I have used [the method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk) without Javascript SDK for Facebook Login. However, when I click Cancel button, the dialog box does not close, it reloads instead.

Could not find a solution. Any idea?

My codes

```
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'http://dnm.com/fb-logout.php'));
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
      'scope' => 'email, user_birthday, publish_stream', 
      'display' => 'popup',
      ''cancel_url' => 'http://mydomain.com',
));
      header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook redirect API just redirects to cancel_url if you hit cancel, or to redirect_url if the login was completed successfully. If you don't want your page to be reloaded you need to use the Javascript SDK.